# Why is Hugh Jackman not going to continue to portray Wolverine?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, casting

According to several news sources, Hugh Jackman has decided not to continue to play Wolverine in films after the upcoming *The Wolverine* sequel:

- [Hugh Jackman Will Play Wolverine “One Last Time”: Is This An End Of An Era? [UPDATED]](http://www.slashfilm.com/hugh-jackman-will-play-wolverine-one-last-time-is-this-an-end-of-an-era/)
- [How Long Hugh Jackman Plans To Play Wolverine](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-Long-Hugh-Jackman-Plans-Play-Wolverine-69965.html)
- [Hugh Jackman Will Stop Playing Wolverine in 2017](http://www.tgdaily.com/happyplace/film/131686-hugh-jackman-will-stop-playing-wolverine-in-2017)
- [Hugh Jackman Dishes On When He'll Stop Playing Wolverine In X-Men Films!](http://perezhilton.com/2015-05-08-hugh-jackman-confirms-last-time-playing-wolverine#.Vblt-rdBCM9)

What were the exact reasons he stopped? Was it his choice, or the choice of the movie producers? I doubt they are never making Wolverine movies again, so why did he stop playing future parts as Wolverine?

Comment: Um... He hasn't stopped? He still has an upcoming film.

Comment: That's his last one. He won't be revisiting the part again after that movie.

Comment: I added a few sources to the question. There are many more. If you Google it, there are a great deal of links speaking about it. The one thing I haven't found is an actual answer as to why.

Comment: That's fine, it's just good to explain your question more fully. Sorry I didn't express that...

Comment: He wouldn't be the first to be called "back for one more" where the money was right. Plenty of time to have a change of heart, no matter how determined he sounds now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He thought it was time. [He said on Dr. Oz](http://screenrant.com/why-hugh-jackman-is-retiring-wolverine-3/):

> “This will be my last one. […] It is my last time. It just felt like
>   it was the right time to do it. And let’s be honest, 17 years [note:
>   the Wolverine sequel is scheduled for 2017]. I never thought in a
>   million years it would last, so I’m so grateful to the fans for the
>   opportunity of playing it.
>
> “I kind of have in my head what we’re going to do in this last one. It
>   just feels like this is the perfect way to go out.”

Comment: Wait a second... are you saying that the OP answered his own question... or would have if he'd actually read the articles he posted?